# Identify mint types and solve existing problems

Tags: identification, indoors, mint

I have several mint types growing on my window sill indoors. I have noticed that some problems with them:

- Leggy stems. I have found on internet that this caused by insufficient light.
- Curly leaves - one side of leaf becomes a bit twisted downwards and towards central leaf stem. Reason unknown
- Small discoloring towards yellow color on leaves. Reason unknown.

What may be the source to 2 and 3 problem? What do you recommend to solve them? I do water them regularly, tried to add some universal liquid fertilizer.

Also here are some pictures of mint that I have. Please help me identify them.

[image: probably mojito mint]

[image: probably peppermint]

[image: probably apple mint]

Thank you!

Comment: The final photo may be apple mint, based on the fuzzy texture of the leaves. If it is, the pot is much too small for it. Apple mint gets to be nearly 3 feet tall in garden. It is a huge plant.

Comment: First photo is likely either peppermint or spearmint. They are very hard to tell apart without tasting.

Comment: Please only post one plant per question when looking for identification, or it might get edited/closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For problem no.1, you are right, leggy stems means insufficient light.

Problem no. 2, curly leaves: because of inconsistent watering schedule. In general, potted plants need frequent small quantities of water. If they receive infrequent watering, the venation and the rest of the leaf develop at different speed, resulting in curling. In case of changing the watering schedule to make it more frequent and with less water, affected leaves won't turn back to normal, but new leaves will be ok.

Problem no. 3, small discoloring towards yellow color on leaves: because the plant doesn't have optimal conditions (light and water), its leaves age more rapidly. If the leaves at the base are expected to turn yellow over time, the upper leaves age more rapidly because they are curled. Already affected leaves will not turn back to normal, but new leaves will be ok - like at problem no.2.